# is isset method different for a drop down menu than a text input?

Tags: php, html

If I use `isset()` for a text input then I write it like this:

`$newpass = (isset($_POST['newpass'])) ? $_POST['newpass'] : '';`

Now if I have a drop down menu like below:

```
<select name="students">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="john">John Doe</option>
<option value="Mike">Mike Smith</option>
</select>
```

Then can I use the same type of isset as I have used for text input:

`$studentsdrop = (isset($_POST['students'])) ? $_POST['students'] : '';`

or is the isset different fro a drop down menu?

Comment: If you had actually tried the code before asking this question you would have found that it works and not had to have spent time asking this question.

Comment: I suggest you read a little more about how PHP works (or server-side scripting in general) and how it is used to process forms.

Comment: Why would it be different? It's received as just another text field. Also `isset()` is just like `@()`, except that the former obstructs debugging forevermore.

Comment: @Sammitch I know it works but I wanted to know if this is technically correct way of doing it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) checks to see if a variable exists and that it is not set to NULL. It is not related to HTML at all.

In your case:

```
$studentsdrop = (isset($_POST['students'])) ? $_POST['students'] : '';
```

As long as you knew that `students` was going to be present you wouldn't need this.
The most common time isset() is used upon form submits, is determining a checkbox. For example if you submit a form that has a checkbox, and that checkbox was not checked, it would not be passed into the `$_POST` variable. This is crucial to use:

`$checkbox_name = isset($_POST['checkbox_name']) ? $_POST['checkbox_name'] : '';`

In the case of a `select` the `$_POST` variable will always return, even if it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$newpass = (isset($_POST['newpass'])) ? $_POST['newpass'] : '';
```

checks if a variable called `newpass` was posted into the script.

The option select values can be obtained by javascript/jQuery and posted to a php script (server-side) for action either by AJAX or by GET/POST. Here is an example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#mySelect').change(function() {
                    var sel = $(this).val();
                    //alert(sel);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "another_php_file.php",
                        data: 'theOption=' + sel,
                        success: function(data) {
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<select name="students" id="mySelect">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="john">John Doe</option>
    <option value="Mike">Mike Smith</option>
</select>
```

---

File: ANOTHER_PHP_FILE.php

```
$theVar = $_POST['theOption'];
echo 'I received [' . $theVar . ']';
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use `isset` at all. in either case

Comment: -1 it is bad practice to allow for PHP notices to occur on _purpose_. (which is what would happen if those postvars were not set.

Comment: +1 meme coders confuse notices and errors, seldomly understand the purpose of debug hints.